# Detect whether a Python string is a number or a letter

Tags: python, string, ascii

How can I detect either numbers or letters in a string? I am aware you use the ASCII codes, but what functions take advantage of them?

Comment: See [this list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), particularly `str.isdigit()` and `str.isalpha()`.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132078/8321339

Answer (score 165, accepted):

### Check if string is *nonnegative* digit (integer) and alphabet

You may use [**`str.isdigit()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and [**`str.isalpha()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to check whether a given string is a *nonnegative* integer (0 or greater) and alphabetical character, respectively.

Sample Results:

```
# For alphabet
>>> 'A'.isdigit()
False
>>> 'A'.isalpha()
True

# For digit
>>> '1'.isdigit()
True
>>> '1'.isalpha()
False
```

### Check for strings as positive/negative - integer/float

`str.isdigit()` returns `False` if the string is a *negative* number or a float number. For example:

```
# returns `False` for float
>>> '123.3'.isdigit()
False
# returns `False` for negative number
>>> '-123'.isdigit()
False
```

If you want to **also check for the *negative* integers and [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)**, then you may write a custom function to check for it as:

```
def is_number(n):
    try:
        float(n)   # Type-casting the string to `float`.
                   # If string is not a valid `float`, 
                   # it'll raise `ValueError` exception
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> is_number('123')    # positive integer number
True

>>> is_number('123.4')  # positive float number
True
 
>>> is_number('-123')   # negative integer number
True

>>> is_number('-123.4') # negative `float` number
True

>>> is_number('abc')    # `False` for "some random" string
False
```

### Discard "NaN" (not a number) strings while checking for number

The above functions will return `True` for the "NAN" (Not a number) string because for Python it is valid float representing it is not a number. For example:

```
>>> is_number('NaN')
True
```

In order to check whether the number is "NaN", you may use [**`math.isnan()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) as:

```
>>> import math
>>> nan_num = float('nan')

>>> math.isnan(nan_num)
True
```

Or if you don't want to import additional library to check this, then you may simply check it via comparing it with itself using `==`. Python returns `False` when `nan` float is compared with itself. For example:

```
# `nan_num` variable is taken from above example
>>> nan_num == nan_num
False
```

Hence, above **function `is_number` can be updated to return `False` for `"NaN"`** as:

```
def is_number(n):
    is_number = True
    try:
        num = float(n)
        # check for "nan" floats
        is_number = num == num   # or use `math.isnan(num)`
    except ValueError:
        is_number = False
    return is_number
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> is_number('Nan')   # not a number "Nan" string
False

>>> is_number('nan')   # not a number string "nan" with all lower cased
False

>>> is_number('123')   # positive integer
True

>>> is_number('-123')  # negative integer
True

>>> is_number('-1.12') # negative `float`
True

>>> is_number('abc')   # "some random" string
False
```

### Allow Complex Number like "1+2j" to be treated as valid number

The above function will still return you `False` for the [*complex numbers*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric). If you want your **`is_number` function to treat *complex numbers* as valid number**, then you need to type cast your passed string to [**`complex()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) instead of [**`float()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float). Then your `is_number` function will look like:

```
def is_number(n):
    is_number = True
    try:
        #      v type-casting the number here as `complex`, instead of `float`
        num = complex(n)
        is_number = num == num
    except ValueError:
        is_number = False
    return is_number
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> is_number('1+2j')    # Valid 
True                     #      : complex number 

>>> is_number('1+ 2j')   # Invalid 
False                    #      : string with space in complex number represetantion
                         #        is treated as invalid complex number

>>> is_number('123')     # Valid
True                     #      : positive integer

>>> is_number('-123')    # Valid 
True                     #      : negative integer

>>> is_number('abc')     # Invalid 
False                    #      : some random string, not a valid number

>>> is_number('nan')     # Invalid
False                    #      : not a number "nan" string
```

***PS: Each operation for each check depending on the type of number comes with additional overhead. Choose the version of `is_number` function which fits your requirement.***

Comment: This is a wonderfully complete and well-described answer. +1

Comment: Good answer but doesn't handle TypeError exception. Like when you pass a list to the `is_number` function.

Comment: @Amin That is by design. Functions should not implicitly compress the exceptions. For example, what'll happen if you do `float([1, 2, 3])` ? It'll raise `TypeError exception`. However if you want to compress all the error, you can just remove `ValueError` from `try/except` to make my function compress all the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

For a string of length 1 you can simply perform `isdigit()` or `isalpha()`

If your string length is greater than 1, you can make a function something like..

```
def isinteger(a):
    try:
        int(a)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```